# Change font only in a tikzpicture in beamer document class

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, fonts

I'm doing a presentatin with the `beamer` documentclass. I use `tikzpicture` to annotate a figure. I do it like this

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics{somepicture}};
\node[anchor = west] at (5,0) {Some text with $some math$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

I'm trying to annotate this figure, which I made with `xmgrace`. The default font in this program is Helvetica, if I'm not wrong. So I would like to change the font of every text within my `tikzpicture` into an Helvetica font. But I cannot find any solution for this. The font of the `tikzpicture` does not seem to change at all ...

Comment: The easiest thing would be to use Helvetica for the whole beamer document, `\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}` does this for you https://www.ctan.org/pkg/helvet

Comment: Adding `\tikzset{every node/.append style={font=\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}}` changes the text font, but not the math font, so perhaps not good enough.

Comment: Or you can just say `\begin{tikzpicture}[font={\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}]` which should, I think, change it for non-nodes as well. (Some nodes don't seem to count as node-nodes although I'm not sure what the distinction is based on.)

Comment: @cfr Your comment sounds like it could answer the question. Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: @samcarter Please just undelete your answer since you've already written it!

Answer (score 1):

To convert [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245946/change-font-only-in-a-tikzpicture-in-beamer-document-class?noredirect=1#comment688812_245946)s comment into a (partial) answer that does not deal with math:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}
test in normal font

\begin{tikzpicture}[font={\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}]
\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] at (0,0) {test in phv};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]